# MS Windows 10 rights for Tablet PC Settings?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, non-admin

I work for a company with tightly locked down admin permissions on our Win 10 laptops. I need to occasionally tweak the **Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Tablet PC Settings**, but as a normal user am locked out.

Our Help Desk is offering me temporary local admin, which would work - ONCE.  After that, every time I need to tweak or calibrate, I'd have the same 4 hour SLA wait time for the Help Desk, again.

Is there a specific Win 10 user access policy I can ask for that would give me  permanent access to these functions, as non-admin user, without opening the permissions so wide they will deny it out-of-hand?

On the dialog mentioned, I'm looking to be able to

- "Configure your pen and touch displays"
- "Calibrate"
- "Reset"

These seem like fairly benign operations to me. Akin to being able to change display settings on a multi-monitor docking station. So, if there is a specific policy that locks/unlocks this, I'm fairly certain they would allow me to have it.  I would just need to tell them exactly which policy that is.

I've searched the [Win 10 Group Policy spreadsheet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25250) for "Tablet PC", but nothing jumps out.

---

Comment: If you are that tightly locked down, then there is no way (legitimate in your company) to get around the restriction.

Comment: Which particular settings do you need to change? Be very specific, because a general way to bypass your company policies is out of context here.

Comment: @harrymc - Right. I'm looking for least access. I edited my post to indicate the items I'm locked out of that I would like to find a policy for. if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give advice on bypassing the company's policies, so the advice below
needs cooperation by the administrator of your computer or domain.

Tablet PC Settings can be started by running the following command:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe" shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL TabletPC.cpl @1,general
```

Try first to run it directly without Admin permissions.

If this does not work, you might ask the administrator for authority to run this command,
if it can be allowed via GPO.

Last, you could install the free and portable
[RunAsSpc](https://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)
which allows running an application under another account without entering the password.
Verify that it is correctly installed and working, then ask for temporary admin
permission, and with it set up RunAsSpc to run this command for when you will be
without admin permissions. Test everything well before renouncing admin permissions.

Comment: when you say it can be `allowed via GPO`, can you give me exact wording I could provide to the Help Desk admins?  I'm not Windows admin savvy, and they will only try to do exactly what they are asked.  If I word the request improperly I'll get nowhere with it. Thanks.

Comment: My problem here is that I don't know how much time your admin would agree to spend on this. Without taking responsibility, I would ask him to set up a shortcut to run as admin the command that I included above. The method is described for example in [this article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/standard-users-run-program-admin-rights/). In case of a problem see also [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/) for a slight modification of the process.